# Gaussian process where the output is constrained to be 0 or greater

Tags: estimation, inference, gaussian-process

I am trying my hand at simple GP regression and in my case, the output variable can be greater than or equal to zero.

How can one constrain GPs, so that the predictions always stay in the specified range? One thought I had was too regress on the `log` of the data but then the inclusion of 0 is an issue.

Comment: When you *constrain* it, it's no longer a GP, so we need to explore your intentions a little.  One successful approach has been to use the GP as a kind of "link" in a GLM.  For instance, you can posit the existence of an otherwise unobservable GP that determines the intensity of an inhomogeneous Poisson process. That process, in turn, is guaranteed not to produce negative values. Would this be the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber Aha... yes, that sounds like something appropriate. I am new to this and learning. Can you elaborate on your statement that when you constrain it, it is no longer a GP? I remember a while ago coming across the so-called Cox process. Is this something you are hiinting at?

Comment: By definition, each marginal distribution in a GP is Normal.  If you do *anything* to eliminate the possibility of negative values, it cannot be Normal, so you cannot have a GP.  As a practical matter it's no big deal if the GP posits extremely small probabilities that there ever will be negative values, but that doesn't sound like your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense. In my case, the output is normalized event counts, so while they can be a real number, it can never be below 0.