# Modeling a functional relationship with Constrained Gaussian Process regression

Tags: machine-learning, python, gaussian-process, constraint

I searched the site for an answer to this question, but the closest I could find was:

[Gaussian process where the output is constrained to be 0 or greater](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407747/gaussian-process-where-the-output-is-constrained-to-be-0-or-greater)

which doesn't have an answer. So, I have a dataset generated as

$$y=f(\phi,x)+\epsilon$$

where $\phi$ is a $d-$dimensional vector of parameters, $x$ is a scalar, and $y\in[0,1]$. In other words, for each specific set of parameters $\phi$, the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is a function plus some random noise. The function $f$ is highly nonlinear, so I would like to use a Machine Learning model to learn (an approximation to) $f$ from data. The data I have at my disposal are sequences of points $(x_i,y_i)$, for fixed values of the parameter vector $\phi$. In other words, I have $N$ sequences of $m$ points each,

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
(\phi_1,x_{11},y_{11}), (\phi_1,x_{12},y_{12}), \dots, (\phi_1,x_{1m},y_{1m})\\
(\phi_2,x_{21},y_{21}), (\phi_2,x_{22},y_{22}), \dots, (\phi_2,x_{2m},y_{2m})\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
(\phi_N,x_{N1},y_{N1}), (\phi_N,x_{N2},y_{N2}), \dots, (\phi_N,x_{Nm},y_{Nm})\\
\end{array}$$

where for each sequence we have $x_{i1}<x_{i2}<\dots <x_{im}$.

Since Gaussian Processes are a good model for functional relationships, I was thinking of using a Gaussian Process as my Machine Learning model. However, the output of a Gaussian Process is not constrained to be in $[0,1]$, since of course for each $(x,\phi)$, $y$ would be distributed as a Normal random variable. How could I fit such a "nonGaussian" Process in Python? If you think a Gaussian Process is not the right model to use here, what other model could I use?

Comment: Can you transform $y$ such that $g(y) \in (-\infty, \infty)$ and invertible and model that?  That would be my approach... if $y$ can actually equal $0$ or $1$, you could just make the transform such that $g(0)$ is some number smaller than $g(\text{smallest }y \neq 0)$ and similarly for $g(1)$.  After all, $f$ is already highly nonlinear, so $g^{-1}(f)$ isn't going to ruin a nice linear or some such relationship.

Comment: @jbowman sounds interesting. But the transformation must be invertible, because in the end I want to predict $y$, not $g(y)$. Which transform would you suggest? $y$ is not expected to ever equal 0 or 1 (0 would mean a disaster, and 1 is probably unattainable in the real world). I'm pretty sure $y$ never equals 0 or 1 in the training set.

Comment: The logit transform $g(y) = \ln(y / (1-y))$ would do.

Comment: @jbowman ok, so basically you're saying, transform all the $y$ with a logit, and then train a standard Gaussian Process, such as, for example, the one provided by `scikit-learn`https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html, on the transformed data $(\phi, x, g(y))$. Then at inference (prediction) time, I invert the predictions of the GP with $g^{-1}(f)$. Correct?